# Changing WebSphere dataSource schema at runtime

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, websphere, database-schema

Is it possible to change the default schema for a WebSphere data source at runtime?

For example, I have the following jndi configured as:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/test" lookup-on-startup="true" resource-ref="true" />
```

In my ibm-web-bnd.xml:

```
<resource-ref name="jdbc/test" binding-name="jdbc/test" id="TEST_db"/>
```

In my ibm-web-ext.xml:

```
<resource-ref name="jdbc/test" connection-management-policy="DEFAULT" isolation-level="TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED" id="TEST_db"/>
```

I created a wrapper for the dataSource, bean defined as:

```
<bean id="schemaAwareDataSource" class="com.util.SchemaAwareDataSource" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="schemaValue" value="${modifiableSchema}" />
</bean>
```

And the class looks like:

```
public class SchemaAwareDataSource implements DataSource {

     private DataSource dataSource;
     private String schemaValue;

     @Override
     public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

         if(dataSource.getConnection().getSchema().equals(schemaValue)) {
             return dataSource.getConnection();
         }

         dataSource.getConnection().setSchema(schemaValue);
         return dataSource.getConnection();     
     }

     //other implemented methods not shown
}
```

However this is throwing an **java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException** error when the application starts up and calls `dataSource.getConnection().getSchema()` 
 in the getConnection() inmy wrapper class.

When I debug the getConnection() method, **dataSource** is a **com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource** object.

Is there anyway I can accomplish what I'm trying to do here? I want to be able to change the schema value at runtime on a call to getConnection()

Answer (score 1):

SQLFeatureNotSupportedException would be raised when either the JDBC driver or the WebSphere Application Server level (or both) do not support JDBC 4.1.  If using WebSphere Application Server Liberty, you will want to enable the jdbc-4.1 or jdbc-4.2 feature instead of jdbc-4.0.  If using WebSphere Application Server traditional, you will need to ensure you are on a recent enough version for the JDBC 4.1 (or higher) support.  In either case, check that your JDBC driver is JDBC 4.1 or higher compliant by (outside of the application server) invoking connection.getMetaData().getJDBCMajorVersion and connection.getMetaData().getJDBCMinorVersion.

Comment: Adding on, the only version of WebSphere Application Server Traditional that has JDBC 4.1 support is version 9.

Comment: Ugh. We're only on 8.5.5. Guess this won't work then.

Comment: No, you won't be able to do it using the JDBC 4.1 get/set schema methods on 8.5.5.  However, depending on the database you are using you may be able to use an SQL query to get and set the schema, which would allow you to do essentially the same thing.